# How do I call Button command from inside of ListBox.ItemTemplate DataTemplate, to pass parameter without selecting ListBox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, command

I have a problem, that I am facing for a few hours already. Inside of my xaml view I am having a `ListBox`, that defines `DataTemplate` as follows:

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height ="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height ="30"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--Row 0-->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Style="{StaticResource racetblk}">
                                    Horse name
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Style="{StaticResource racetblk}">
                                    Horse DOB
                        </TextBlock>

                        <!--Row 1-->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=HorseName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource tableItem}"
                                 Height="20"
                                     Width="150"/>
                            <Button Width="50"
                                Margin="5"
                                Height="20"
                                Content="Pick"
                                Background=" #a1c883 "
                                Foreground="White"
                                Command="{Binding PickHorseDataCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lbHorseList, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Birth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Style="{StaticResource tableItem}"
                                 Height="20"/>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
```

Inside of the template `<!--Row 1-->` I have a button, that supposed to trigger command inside of my ViewModel command supposed to be trigerred after typing text inside of a `TextBox`:

```
private ICommand pickHorseDataCommand;
        public ICommand PickHorseDataCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (pickHorseDataCommand == null)
                    pickHorseDataCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    o =>
                    {
                        int horseIndex = (int)o;
                        HorseDataWrapper horse = Horses[horseIndex];
                        LoadedHorse horseFromList = allHorses.Where(i => i.Name == horse.HorseName).FirstOrDefault();
                        horse.Birth = horseFromList.Birth.ToString();
                        var dupa = horse;
                    });
                return pickHorseDataCommand;
            }
        }
```

There are two problems with this. First of all, the command is not trigerred at all, I belive, that I supposed to bind the command somehow using `RelativeSource`, but until now I did not managed to do it.

Another thing is, that `CommandParameter` is binded to `SelectedIndex`, so the `ListBox` item have to be selected when pushing the button, to make the binding come true. I could not find any other solution to do the binding without selecting the item. Maybe you have any alternatives?

I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command is defined in the view model, you could bind to it like this:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.PickHorseDataCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
```

If you need the `SelectedIndex` in the view model, you should define a source property and bind the `ListBox`'s `SelectedIndex` property to this one instead of using a `CommandParameter`:

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding YourIndexProperty}" ... />
```

The `Execute` method of the command can then access the index property directly:

```
int index = this.YourIndexProperty;
```

Another option may be to pass a reference to the current item itself, instead of using the index, as a parameter to the command:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this AncestorType need to be specified

`Command="{Binding DataContext.pickHorseDataCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=,Mode=FindAncestor}}"`